# I want to run a infinite loop and check for a specific condition at the set minute how can i do it

Tags: python

```
from datetime import datetime
check_min=[9,15,25,35,45,55]
check_sec=1
time_now=datetime.now()
min_now=time_now.minute
second_now=time_now.second
something=True
while True:
    if min_now in check_min and something==True:
        print("Yes")
        something=False
```

I am trying to run a infinite loop which checks for a specific condition in the given list of minutes.The loop is getting stuck if the programme is executed in the minutes when not in the list,How do I solve this?

Comment: don't do it like this. create a task that runs at the desired time using taskmanager or cron, and have your code just do what is supposed to do without handling the execution time.

Comment: `min_now` never gets updated once the loop starts.

Comment: When you write getting stuck, does it mean the code crash ? computer stop responding ? and the reason you loop never exist is that you only check min_now once, you need to check it inside the loop

Comment: Put min_now & second_now inside while loop.

Comment: thanks everyone ,I am new here so thanks for the Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get `min_now` every time the loop repeats:

```
from datetime import datetime
check_min=[9,15,25,35,45,55]
check_sec=1
something=True
while True:
    time_now=datetime.now()
    min_now=time_now.minute
    second_now=time_now.second
    if min_now in check_min and something==True:
        print("Yes")
        something=False
```

(I put `second_now` in there also, but if you are not checking seconds then you don't need it. Depends on the program.)

Comment: so it will print Yes only once, set something to false and never enter the condition again since something won't be true ever again.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Correct, I believe that is the OP's intended behavior.

Comment: @EliHarold,Thank you for the support,the above code is working fine,Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Sure thing @Deadsshott !